# razor javascript var array Response.Write checking a Model data changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Upgrading my application from MVC3 (aspx / Linq-to-Sql) to MVC5 (razor / EF 6.1), I am getting an error Colon Expected, and the word "Test" appears on the top of the screen, and can not check if the model has been changed. I use this script to show check mark on buttons if the contents of a certain page for example History data has been changed.

In MVC5 I use:

```
var missingActions = [@{
Response.Write(Model.Symptoms == null ? "\"History\"," : "");
Response.Write(Model.Test == null ? "\"Testing\"," : "");
}  ""];
```

In MVC3 I used:

```
var missingActions = [<%{
    Response.Write(Model.Symptoms == null ? "\"History\"," : "");
    Response.Write(Model.Test == null ? "\"Testing\"," : "");
    %>  ""];
```

I noticed, when I debug both applications, placing the mouse on the word Model:
In MVC5, I get:

```
MyProject.Domain.Models.Visit WebViewPage<Visit>.Model Get the Model property of the associated System.Web.MVC.ViewDataDictionary object.
```

While in MVC I get:

```
Model | {myProject.Models.Visit}
```

I can view the Model properties in MVC3 but not in MVC5.

Would appreciate to learn what could be wrong with the script and why it displays the word "Test" on the screen, and get the model properties.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `""` from the ending?

Comment: I have updated my question after Afzaal comment.